# PhpStorm collision ignore insteadof

Tags: php, laravel, phpstorm

I have this annoying message in my test after updating PhpStorm.

[image]

The error says:

> Trait method 'beginDatabaseTransaction' will not be applied, because it collides with 'RefreshDatabase'

Why PhpStorm ignores **insteadof** ?

I there any way to disable this or fix it?

Thanks.

This is the whole test:

```
<?php


namespace Tests\Feature\Auth\User;

use App\Application\Traits\RefreshDatabaseTransactionLess;
use App\Domain\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseMigrations;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\RefreshDatabase;
use Hash;
use Tests\TestCase;

class LoginUserTest extends TestCase
{
    use RefreshDatabase, DatabaseMigrations, RefreshDatabaseTransactionless {
        RefreshDatabaseTransactionless::beginDatabaseTransaction insteadof RefreshDatabase;
    }

    protected function postLoginRoute()
    {
        return route('auth.user.login');
    }


    public function testUserCanLogin()
    {
        $password = 'password';

        $user = factory(User::class)->create([
           'email' => 'test@test.com',
           'password' => Hash::make($password)
        ]);

        $response = $this->post($this->postLoginRoute(), [
            'email' => $user->email,
            'password' => $password
        ]);

        $response->assertSuccessful();
        $response->assertJsonStructure([
            'token',
            'type',
            'expires'
        ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: 1) What's your IDE version exactly? 2) Can you provide a sample code (looks like Laravel, but what version etc). Ideally if you could share some ready to use test project. P.S. Yes, there were some fixes/improvements in 2019.3 but I do not know if this is a new issue or whatnot.

Comment: @LazyOne Yes it is Laravel 5.8,  i'm using mongodb, thats why I  need to have all this Jazz, PhpStorm version is 2019.3. I have added whole test.

Comment: @LazyOne and yes, this problem appears just after the update.

Comment: Has to be a bug -- I see the same in 2019.3.1 EAP build. It was not in 2019.2 as it's a new inspection implemented for 2019.3 (https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-12120). It could be related to/duplicate of https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-47532...

Comment: ... but I'm not 100% sure. Therefore I suggest to post a ticket at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WI and provide a code to reproduce (in theory the same code as you did here would be enough .. but then devs have to add missing code themselves .. which is inconvenient as they are not PHP devs). I suggest this: create brand new Laravel project, add those few classes (that Test + some content for `RefreshDatabaseTransactionLess` -- just declaration without implementation would be enough) and provide whole zipped folder as an attachment (you can omit `vendor` folder content).

Comment: Devs will then check and decide if it's a dupe or a separate issue. You can also reference this question as well (in case if they need some more info etc).

Answer (score 1):

If you are running PhpStorm 2019.3, it's a bug from the new inspection introduced in this release: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-43949.

Under certain circumstances the inspection appears to ignore the `insteadof` keyword.

Answer (score 0):

This is fixed as of (approx) today. Update your IDEs and it should work.